# Form does not get validated

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this piece of code, however, it is not validating the form...

Note that this isn't the entire page, just a snippet. The code should validate the different tags, but I don't want to do it with the html attributes. It needs to be done in JavaScript...

Where did I go wrong with my coding?

```
//To disable the radio buttons
function disableStuffNo(){
    //random comment to post
    document.getElementById("tele").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("whatsapp").disabled = false;
    //random comment to post
    document.getElementById("call").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("email").disabled = false;
}

 function disableStuffYes(){
    document.getElementById("tele").disabled = true;
     //random comment to post
    document.getElementById("whatsapp").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("call").disabled = true;
    //random comment to post
    document.getElementById("email").disabled = true;
}

//To validate the form
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["Order"]["Fname"].value;
    var b = document.forms["Order"]["Lname"].value;
    var c = document.forms["Order"]["topic"].value;

    if (a == ""||b == ""||c == "") {
    alert("Everything must be filled out");
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="Order" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display:block;" onsubmit="validateForm()">
    <fieldset>
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        First Name: <input type="text" id="Fname" maxlength="40"<br/><br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="Lname"  maxlength="40"><br/><br/>
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        Occasion: <input type="text" id="topic"  max="50"><br/><br/>
        Gender:<br/>
        Female <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="Female">
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        Male <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male"><br/>
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        You do wish to schedule an appointment to discuss further? 
        Yes <input type="radio" id="yes" name="answer" value="Yes" checked onclick="disableStuffYes">
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        No <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="No"onclick="disableStuffNo;"><br/>
        Telephone Number: <input type="text" id="tele" maxlength="20" value="1(876)"><br/>
        Through:<br/>
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        Whatsapp <input type="radio" id="whatsapp" name="choice" value="Whatsapp">
        Call <input type="radio" id="call" name="choice" value="Call">
         <!--random comment so i can post-->
        Email <input type="radio" id="email" name="choice" value="Email">
        <br/>
        <br/><br/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <!--random comment so i can post-->
        Please indicate the details of your request :)<br/>
        <textarea maxlength="1500" rows="20" cols="100">
        </textarea><br/>
         <!--random comment so i can post-->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you attached ```validateForm``` function to any event handlers?

Comment: There is a closing brace missing in your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        Firstname <input type="text" id="fname" maxlength="40"><br>
        Lastname <input type="text" id="lname" maxlength="40"><br>
        Topic <input type="text" id="topic" maxlength="50"><br>
        <button id="testbutton">Check form</button>

        <script>
            var isFormValid = function() {
                var a = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                var b = document.getElementById("lname").value;
                var c = document.getElementById("topic").value;

                if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "") {
                    alert("Something is missing");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            };

            var button = document.getElementById("testbutton");

            button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                if (isFormValid()) {
                    console.log("Form is valid");
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually worked without any problem for me. I just copy/paste the code and it worked.
What i would suggest is the following:

1) Try to include the javascript code directly inside your html just before closing the body tag

```
<script>
//To validate the form
function validateForm() {
  var a = document.forms["Order"]["Fname"].value;
  var b = document.forms["Order"]["Lname"].value;
  var c = document.forms["Order"]["topic"].value;

  if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "") {
     alert("Everything must be filled out");
     return false;
  }  
 }
 </script>
```

2) If it works, check that the link to your external javascript file is correct. You can do that by Inspecting Element and checking the console for a 404 error ("file.js could not be found").

Because it worked for me, i really do not think it is a code error and will probably turn out to be option 2.